# Write function strLetterCount and return new string with the characters followed by the count

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function strLetterCount(word) that takes the string input, and returns a string followed by the count of occurrences.
Ex:

```
strLetterCount("coconut"); // "c2o2n1u1t1"
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
   function strLetterCount (word){
   let results = ""
   for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      let charAt = word.charAt(i)
      let count = 0

      results += charAt

      for (let j = 0; j < word.length ; j++)
      {
         if(word.charAt(j) === charAt)
         {
            count++
         }
      }
      results += count
   }
   return results;
}
```

But the issue is that it returns c2o2c2o2n1u1t1 instead of c2o2n1u1t1. I'm not sure how to get rid of the duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function strLetterCount (word){
   let results = ""
   for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      let charAt = word.charAt(i)
      if (!results.includes(charAt)) // <----------------------
      {
        let count = 0

        results += charAt

        for (let j = 0; j < word.length ; j++)
        {
           if(word.charAt(j) === charAt)
           {
              count++
           }
        }
        results += count
       }
   }
   return results;
}

console.log(strLetterCount("coconut"));
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using `String.prototype.split` function, you can convert string into `char` array.
- Based on that char array, using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can get the duplicated char info.
- With that duplicated info, can get the string linked using `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
console.log(strLetterCount("coconut")); // "c2o2n1u1t1"

function strLetterCount(word) {
  const wordArr = word.split('');
  const duplicates = wordArr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur] ? acc[cur] ++ : acc[cur] = 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return Object.entries(duplicates).map(([key, value]) => key + value).join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function strLetterCount(word) {
  let results = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    let c = word.charAt(i)
    results[c] = (results[c] || 0) + 1;
  }
  let r = '';
  for (let c in results)
    r += c + results[c];
  return r;
}

console.log(strLetterCount("coconut")); // "c2o2n1u1t1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [String split method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), the [Array map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and the [Array join method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) you can do it in a single line of code

```js
const strLetterCount = word => [...new Set(word.split(''))].map(l => `${l}${word.split(l).length - 1}`).join('');


console.log(strLetterCount('coconut'));
```